# Warnings thrown by sparse

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have the following warnings being thrown by sparse when I run spare on my Linux driver with the following options:
`make C=2 CF=-D__CHECK_ENDIAN__`

My function is:

```
static inline u8 rsi_get_register_addr(u8 *addr, u16 offset)
{
        return (le16_to_cpu(*(u16 *)&addr[offset]) & 0x7000) >> 12;
}
```

The warning that is reported by sparse is:
`warning: cast to restricted __le16`

Can someone help me with understanding what has gone wrong here?

Another issue that I am currently facing is in the following line:

```
__le16 values[20] = {0xf0, 0xfb, 0xf2, 0xf1};
```

Sparse gives the following warning:
 `warning: incorrect type in initializer (different base types) expected restricted __le16
got int`

Another issue is:
`seq = cpu_to_le16(tmp_hdr->seq >> 4);`

The error that I get for this is: `restricted __le16 degrades to integer`.

Not sure how to resolve this.

How do I rectify all of these issues?

Comment: 1. Try with `__le16 val[20] = {0x00f0, 0x00fb etc..}` 2. return (u8)((le16_to_cpu(*(u16 *)&addr[offset]) & 0x7000) >> 12)

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: oops ! Try `__le16 val[20] = {cpu_to_le16(0xf0), cpu_to_le16(0xfb) etc..}`

Comment: For 2, try __le16 val[20] = {cpu_to_le16(0xf0), cpu_to_le16(0xfb)..}

Comment: For 1, try (le16_to_cpu(*(__le16 *)&addr[offset]) & 0x7000) >> 12;

Comment: Thanks Joe. Both #1 and #2 worked for me. However I have another issue. Can you please help me resolve this?                        seq = cpu_to_le16(tmp_hdr->seq >> 4); The error that I get for this is: restricted __le16 degrades to integer
Not sure how to resolve this. Please help!

Comment: Hi, I just need a clarification.  Does sparse tool identify endian-related issues only when we use macros like __le32_to_cpu()? Or can it identify all types of endianness related issues like bitfields, union, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

For the 1st issue

`(le16_to_cpu(*(__le16 *)&addr[offset]) & 0x7000) >> 12;`

For the 2nd issue

`__le16 val[20] = {cpu_to_le16(0xf0), cpu_to_le16(0xfb)..}`

For the 3rd issue

`u16 seq = (le16_to_cpu(tmp_hdr->seq) >> 4);`

For more details read this [link](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/IA64wiki/SparseAnnotations)

Comment: #3 doesn;t work. Joe, Let me give you more details regarding #3, in struct tmp_hdr, seq member is declared of type __le16. Also, I had declared u16 seq = (tmp_hdr->seq >> 4). Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I am glad it worked. However, my code looks slightly ugly now. Here's what I wanted to do:                                  msg[6] = cpu_to_le16(le16_to_cpu(wh->seq_ctrl) >> 4);
Doesn't this look ugly? Can I avoid the cpu_to_le16 + le16_to_cpu conversion together in some way.

Comment: As I understand, the __le16 or __le32 typedefs are majorly for type checking, checking that the value contained in them is a little endian one. Am I right?